# Database Bound Drop Downs in dynamic table Jquery

Tags: jquery, object, dynamic

I am creating a dynamic HTML table in JQuery. Each table row has 2-3 drop downs which are bound to database. Currently while creating rows and cells I am calling a function that creates a drop down and add OPTIONS to the drop down and add this to my row cell. Drop down options are same for all the rows. But I want to optimize this. What  I am thinking is like I have an **PRE filled** drop down object without any id assigned to it and I could simply add that drop down object to one of my row cell and assign a unique id to it . I am not sure how to do this is it possible anyway?

Comment: What is your back-end language? How do you fetch the options?

Comment: back end is C# and I am fetching options through a AJAX call.

Comment: Show some of your code please. Also your view and javascript (the relevant parts)